# Считывание с изменяющегося файла

Tags: python, файлы, python-3.x, gui

Есть текстовый файл, который постоянно изменяется с некоторой периодичностью. Примерно каждые ~5-15 секунд в нём появляется новая запись, которая должна быть тут же считана программой и после проверки на какие-то условия эта запись должна появиться в окне графического интерфейса. Мои попытки с циклами оказались тщетными, либо программа работала, но не совсем так, как надо. Как можно решить такую задачу? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28348669/5741205)

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [How can I tail a log file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12523044/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поведение может зависеть от платформы, но можно просто периодически пытаться дальше файл прочитать после EOF (или в худшем случае запоминать последнюю позицию и вызывать `file.seek(last_position)` на переоткрытом файле), предполагая что в файл новые строки добавляются только в конце (как в лог-файле)—нет других изменений. Например, чтобы показывать в GUI последнюю строчку в файле, которая соответствует заданному регулярному выражению (аналог `tail -f file | grep -Pe regex`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: grep-tail <regex> <file>"""
import collections
import functools
import re
import sys
import tkinter.messagebox

def filter_lastline(file, predicate):
    """Find the last line in *file* that satisfies *predicate*."""
    lines = collections.deque(filter(predicate, file), maxlen=1)
    try:
        return lines.pop().rstrip('\n')
    except IndexError:
        return ''  # not found

def update_label(root, label, last_line):
    current = label['text']
    new = last_line()
    if new and current != new:
        label['text'] = new  # update label
    root.after(1000, update_label, root, label, last_line)  # poll in a second

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # hide the main window
    try:  # handle command-line arguments
        regex_string, path = sys.argv[1:]
        found = re.compile(regex_string).search
        file = open(path)
    except Exception as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror('wrong command-line arguments',
                                     'error: %s\n%s' % (e, __doc__),
                                     parent=root)
        sys.exit(__doc__)

    last_line = functools.partial(filter_lastline, file, found)
    label = tkinter.Label(root, text=last_line()
                          or '<nothing matched %r>' % regex_string)
    label.pack()

    update_label(root, label, last_line)  # start polling

    # center window
    root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' %
              root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Пример:

```
$ ./grep-tail 'python[23]' /var/log/syslog
```

#### Комментарии к реализации

1. файл является итератором над строками в Питоне, поэтому `filter(predicate, file)` генерирует строки в файле, которые удовлетворяют `predicate(line)` критерию (регулярному выражению в данном случае).
2. `deque(it, maxlen=1)` поглощает итератор, оставляя самое большее только последний элемент.
3. При повторном вызове `filter_lastline(file, predicate)`, `file` читается с последней позиции (EOF—с предыдущего конца файла). Можно ли не переоткрывая файл прочитать новые строки таким способом, может зависеть от платформы
4. `root.after(1000, f, *args)` вызывает `f(*args)` через секунду, поэтому:

   ```
   def f(*args):
       # do something
       # continue loop
       root.after(1000, f, *args)
   ```

   создаёт цикл, не блокируя GUI. Нельзя написать:

   ```
   def loop():
       while True:
           f(*args)
           time.sleep(1)
   ```

   так как `loop()` заблокирует GUI и придётся вызов в отдельный поток/процесс помещать. `root.after()` позволяет `f(*args)` в GUI потоке вызывать и модифицировать `label` без проблем.

---

Если файл редко изменяется, то для эффективности можно [`watchdog` модуль](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html) использовать, чтобы вызывать `update_label()` только когда файл действительно поменялся ([в `on_modified()` обратном вызове](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler.on_modified)). В данном случае (обновления через 5-15 секунд), использование `watchdog` было бы излишнем уcложнением (сторонняя зависимость + интеграция с циклом событий):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: grep-tail <regex> <file>"""
import collections
import functools
import os
import re
import sys
import tkinter.messagebox

from watchdog.observers import Observer # $ pip install watchdog
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

def filter_lastline(file, predicate):
    """Find the last line in *file* that satisfies *predicate*."""
    lines = collections.deque(filter(predicate, file), maxlen=1)
    try:
        return lines.pop().rstrip('\n')
    except IndexError:
        return ''  # not found

def update_label(root, label, last_line):
    current = label['text']
    new = last_line()
    if new and current != new:
        label['text'] = new  # update label

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # hide the main window
    try:  # handle command-line arguments
        regex_string, path = sys.argv[1:]
        found = re.compile(regex_string).search
        file = open(path)
    except Exception as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror('wrong command-line arguments',
                                     'error: %s\n%s' % (e, __doc__),
                                     parent=root)
        sys.exit(__doc__)

    last_line = functools.partial(filter_lastline, file, found)
    label = tkinter.Label(root, text=last_line()
                          or '<nothing matched %r>' % regex_string)
    label.pack()

    class EventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
        def on_modified(self, event):
            if event.src_path == path:
                update_label(root, label, last_line)

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(EventHandler(), os.path.dirname(path))
    observer.start()

    # center window
    root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' %
              root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
    root.mainloop()
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()

main()
```

В отличии от предыдущей версии, `update_label()` вызывается только, если входной файл был изменён: нет `root.after()` вызова. Предполагается, что полные строки пишутся—разумно для лог-файлов и строк меньших размера буфера, иначе следует `update_label()` подредактировать, чтобы накапливать данные при каждом вызове пока новая строка не встретится.

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter, threading, time, queue, random, string, os

queue = queue.Queue()  # новые строки

def listener(file: str):
    '''постоянно заново читает файл, новые строки добавляет в queue'''
    line_num = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        lines = list(open(file))
        llen = len(lines)
        if llen != line_num:
            for line in lines[line_num:]: queue.put(line)
            line_num = llen

def checker():
    '''слушает queue, выводит строки в окно'''
    while True:
        line = queue.get()  # которая должна быть тут же считана программой
        if line.strip() and not line == '\n':  # и после проверки на какие-то условия
            gui_text.insert(1.0, line)  # эта запись должна появиться в окне графического интерфейса
        queue.task_done()

def writer(file: str):
    '''Есть текстовый файл, который постоянно изменяется с некоторой периодичностью'''
    if not os.path.isfile(file): print('newfile', file=open(file, 'w'))
    while True:
        t = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10))) + '\n'
        print(t, file=open(file, 'a'))  # в нём появляется новая запись
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))  # Примерно каждые ~5-15 секунд


root = tkinter.Tk()
gui_text = tkinter.Text()
gui_text.pack()

file = 'wqeq.txt'
# запускаем все в потоке
threading.Thread(target=writer, args=[file]).start()
threading.Thread(target=listener, args=[file]).start()
threading.Thread(target=checker).start()
root.mainloop()
```

можно перечитывать файл полностью и сравнивать размер

Answer (score 0):

Переоткрывать файл и делать замену текста: в новом тексте заменять весь объем старого текста на пустое место. В результате будет оставаться только добавленный текст.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: плохое решение.