# Бесконечное чтение из файла

Tags: python

Нужно постоянно читать текст из блокнота, в котором добавляется новый текст.

Как я понял, нужно сделать такое:

```
while True:
   with open("somefile","r") as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
        print(line)
```

Можно ли это сделать как-то по-другому? Или только так?

Comment: А чем этот способ не устраивает? Что хочется улучшить?

Comment: Просто этот файл использует и другая программа тоже, и если они вместе откроют его - выкидывает в ошибку PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: если другая программа открывает в монопольном режиме, то сложно.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Считывание с изменяющегося файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/569677/23044)