# Как считывать информацию с log файла? На Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть лог файл DropsSummoner.log, он периодический обновляется. Мне нужно чтобы после каждого обновления этого файла, выводилось на экран последняя строчка этого файла (я делаю уведомления в телеграм, в итоге эта строчка будет отправлена в телеграм, но эту часть я и сам могу сделать, я не могу придумать как считывать последнюю строчку после каждого обновления файла).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes

Comment: я когда-то пользовался watchdog - работало. под рукой нет, чтоб проверить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Считывание с изменяющегося файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569677/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = '11\n' \
      '12\n' \
      '13\n'

print(txt.splitlines()[-1])
```

вывод

```
13
```

Answer (score 0):

В этой задаче вам поможет уже отмеченный [watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).

Пример кода (ловит изменения в файле и выводит последнюю строку измененного файла на консоль):

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class FileChangeEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, patterns=None, ignore_patterns=None, case_sensitive=False):
        super().__init__(
            patterns=patterns,
            ignore_patterns=ignore_patterns,
            ignore_directories=True,
            case_sensitive=case_sensitive
        ) #принудительно устанавливаем ignore_directories на True, 
          #так как нам нужны только изменения в файлах
    
    def on_modified(self, event):
        with open(event.src_path) as modifiedFile:
            for line in modifiedFile: pass
            print(line)


targetDir = "."
patterns = ("test.txt",) #укажите здесь шаблон, соответствующий отслеживаему файлу (файлам)

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(
    event_handler = FileChangeEventHandler(patterns=patterns), 
    path = targetDir,
    recursive = False
)
observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping")
finally:
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

---

- По поводу шаблонов для файлов можете почитать [тут](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/pathpattern.html).
- Бесконечный цикл нужен, чтобы программа не завершилась сразу после установки *watchdog*. Его можно заменить какой либо полезной нагрузкой (например, *bot_polling()*)
- *Observer* работает в отдельном потоке. То есть основной поток можно занять другими операциями, не боясь, что обработка событий *watchdog* зависнет

Comment: watchdog отсматривает события файловой системы. Ок. Чтобы ловить изменения в одном файле, мне кажется это избыточным, ок. Добавьте обработку последней строки логи? Увидеть увидели, а дальше то, что?

Comment: @Dmitry думаю, тс сам реализует обработку этой  строки. А для примера достаточно обычного *print()*

Comment: Дело ваше, ответ не полон. `print()` каким образом? Читать весь файл? а если там гиг? будем все в память читать? Генератор или `seek` при открытии может помочь

Comment: Привет! Ваш код мне очень помог! Но я столкнулся с еще одной проблемой, код не видит файл с логами, то есть изменения в файле происходят, а на экран ничего не выводится